# Finding an inexpensive long stopover "anywhere"

Tags: online-resources, flight-search-engines

This is not the same as [what is the most advanced flight search engine besides Azuon and Matrix?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/54301/what-is-the-most-advanced-flight-search-engine-besides-azuon-and-matrix) but I would hope an engine "advanced" enough for that one would satisfy this one as well.

The scenario is that one is near XXX and wants to be near YYY by date Z but has no plans for the time in between.

There are search engines that allow an origin and/or destination to be a huge list of places, and one that even allows the word "anywhere."

But as far as I can tell, Kayak, Adioso, Momondo, Skyscanner, & Azuon do not allow "anywhere" as the middle of a multi-city flight.  Matrix allows a list, but can't handle very big lists and doesn't have low-cost airlines.

I understand the arguments about computational complexity, but I spent several years doing complex queries on huge databases and it's not as bad as some questions here make it sound.

Currently, one approach I've figured out is to do two searches with Azuon, put both result sets into a database and then join the table to itself.  That is not entirely satisfactory, because (for example) it won't find options like XXX to DFW then DAL to YYY.

Another is to manually (and tediously) look for matches in the two searches.

And I had forgotten about [this method](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13845/how-do-i-minimize-total-cost-of-separate-flights-to-the-same-destination-plus-op/27454#27454).  But even that won't find everything.

Some engines will find stopovers but won't find very many, and won't show long ones.

I **suspect** I could do it with one of the expensive tools from [OAG](https://www.oag.com/oag-store), but apparently they found some reason to not honor their offer of a free trial.

Comment: Azuon's performance is suspect.  I've seen it say that there are NO flights from anywhere in USA to anywhere in Europe in a one-month time period.  Today I asked for "LAS, DEN, FSM, FWA, DFW, XNA" to central or south America or Canada, over an eight-day period, and it gave me ONLY Southwest to SJU.

Comment: If I was doing this, I'd probably use [flightconnections.com](http://www.flightconnections.com/) to figure out what cities ZZZ can serve as one-stop connections between XXX and YYY, pick a few that sounded interesting, and see what the fares were on two separate tickets XXX–ZZZ and ZZZ–YYY.  This doesn't cover all of your desiderata, though:  this method wouldn't reveal the DFW/DAL case, and finding the cheapest fares among all the ZZZ's would be difficult.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert: That's an improvement over my workaround, as it reduces the size of the two result sets.  Although I failed to make it clear that XXX and YYY also aren't single airports, because the time period covered is usually more than a week, and I can bicycle 300-400 kilometers in a week.

Comment: The problem with stopovers in a fare component is that you may invoke the Higher Intermediate Point rule. This rule says that you have to check that, if you had constructed your itinerary as two separate components with a fare break point at the stopover, this construction would not be more expensive than your through-fare with a stopover. (This is done recursively if there are several stopovers.) If it is, you have to raise the price of your through-fare component to match the more expensive construction. This is something a lot of pricing engines struggle to get right.

Comment: Ah, but the point is to find the options and look at the prices, not to just assume a particular one is cheapest.

Comment: And in fact, if Azuon is correct, KEF-EDI-BCN costs about twenty percent more than EDI-BCN & KEF-EDI

Comment: _"I understand the arguments about computational complexity, but I spent several years doing complex queries on huge databases and it's not as bad as some questions here make it sound."_ - a flight system is not mapped as a relational database, but rather a network graph; so set-like operations don't really apply.

Comment: Neither was some of the stuff I worked on.  No matter how they store it, a route has two endpoints, a date/time, and a price.  So a collection of routes can easily be a four-column table.  One of the things I did before retiring was to take a similar list of paths from a map and join it to itself to list all the paths between two specific nodes.  If there had been a cost associated with each path, it would have been trivial to order by cost. And it would be trivial to add a WHERE First_Leg.Arrival < Second_Leg.Departure

Comment: @WGrileau Ah that's not quite true. Although (in the simplest approximation) each city pair will have a tariff of fares associated with it, whether a particular fare is valid or not on a given set of flights connecting the two cities is not trivial to check. You can build yourself a table with this information if you like, but that isn't what is happening under the surface.

Comment: I think you missed details in the question.  If I wanted the valid fare for a single ticket, I wouldn't be checking separate fares.  Imagine changing my constraint to WHERE Second_Trip.Departure - First_Trip.Arrival IS BETWEEN 2*Days AND 10*Days;

Answer (score 2):

Try [JetPuzzle](https://jetpuzzle.net/) extension for Chrome. It really does well.

You can try to put any two points and it will list you a huge amount of options including those with literally "anywhere" legs. And making things even smoother, it proposes you variants with arbitrary number of stopovers.

[image]

Comment: Hmmm.  I don't like Chrome, but this is worth a try...

Comment: I don't think this quite fits what the OP wants because it appears as if they want to stay longer than a typical layover at the intermediate city.

Comment: Actually, I tried it, and was extremely unimpressed.  I don't consider _four_ a "huge amount" but that's all I got in each try.  And all of them were quite expensive.  One of them had me landing in Montreal and taking off from Boston about thirty hours later.  But at least it did show some interesting routes.

Comment: It's all depends on destination, season, etc., and with this tool I picked really interesting bargains before. All in all, I don't think you have plenty of choice with your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Simply look for the full trip on any site ie. with your preferred starting and end points. The results will give you a clue of the paths flight companies take to reach your destination and therefore what cities will be feasible as stopovers.

Once you see something you like, then use a multi-city booking to include that city, with a day or so in between departures. If it's all with the same airline with daily flights, your costs will be roughly the same as the single flight.

Comment: Doesn't meet the goal.  YYZ-KEF-BRU is a reasonable price, but what if YYZ-MÉX and MEX-BRU were. Also low enough bought separately?  That's just an example, but the point is that with the time-intensive method I mentioned, I have more than once found fun routes that would never show up in any search engine I'm aware of.