# What are some tips and tricks for finding the cheapest flight when luggage and other fees are not revealed until far into the booking process?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, tips-and-tricks, flight-search-engines, fees-and-charges

I'm finding it ever more frustrating recently to compare and find the truly cheapest flights.

Flight search engines are more and more useless as airlines game the system increasingly to list low prices when you'll actually have to pay much more, especially with checked luggage.

Often the full amount of fees and taxes will not be shown until personal information and even credit card details have been entered. You can hunt each airline's sites for their luggage fees but they can be hard to find and easy to misinterpret.

For my current situation looking to fly from South Korea to a cheap destination in Southeast Asia, the full price often turns out to be double the advertised price!

I'm well into my trip so ditching my backpack is not an option. I'm looking for tips from experienced air travellers on how to select a flight when a huge proportion of the price seems to be hidden and obfuscated and seemingly unknowable in advance.

Comment: Related search: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/54301/what-is-the-most-advanced-flight-search-engine-besides-azuon-and-matrix

Comment: So apparently [Google Flights is supposed to have this feature](https://support.google.com/travel/answer/9074247?hl=en) but I can only see a checkbox for carry-ons and nothing for checked bags. [An article on "The Points Guy"](https://thepointsguy.com/news/google-flights-checked-baggage-fee-feature/) points out that this feature is currently only for US domestic flights )-:

Comment: I heard you get the best price if you pay for your flight 51 days in advance.

Comment: I thought we discussed this prior -- I still maintain this is very complicated because very often fares not even available on any other websites but the airline itself will contain baggage and might be a better deal of what you need, depending.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there any flight price search engines with baggage allowance included?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/9921/are-there-any-flight-price-search-engines-with-baggage-allowance-included)

Comment: *Largely* a duplicate of the 'luggage' question, but this one also asks about *other fees*, such as costs associated with seating. Voting to leave open.

Comment: @chx: Man how did I not find that? I Googled both the general internet *and* StackExchange specifically. I'll have a look at it now...

Comment: @JanDoggen: Yes the luggage seems to be the biggest part of the hidden/last-second fees, but it's all non-obvious by design so I asked about fees in general. Basically these days you often don't get the breakdown of fees until you enter your personal details and sometimes your payment card details. You can put in fake ones but the browser might remember them. All kinds of extra annoyance anyway...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For Aussies such as yourself, my site - [Beat That Flight](https://www.beatthatflight.com.au/) ([and beta Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.au.beatthatflight)) might be able to help a bit.

For example, on [a search from Sydney to Hong Kong](https://bookings.beatthatflight.com.au/flights/syd1610hkg29101) - on the left side, you can see baggage options, with the perceived difference in price:

[image]

It's not perfect, and relies on data on upstream providers as well, but makes an effort to try and calculate luggage.

I've seen others block searches for airlines like RyanAir in the past as it was just too difficult with all their crazy fee addons, but suspect you'll see more and more features like this in time to come.

Comment: I found the interface confusing and if you're looking for beta tests, semi-retired computer programmer here (-: I do have to fight with it a bit but it is indeed doing what I want! Also, why only for Australians??

Comment: @hippietrail thanks, I'm still growing it part time.  FOcusing on deals for Australians but anyone can use the website.

Answer (score 7):

[Kayak](https://www.kayak.com/) is not my first choice of search engines, but I do note that it now attempts to factor carry-ons and checked bags into the price.  You have to start the search and then change the zero bags default in the filters.

[Kiwi.com](https://www.kiwi.com/) (which I also am not thrilled with) will tell you which flights allow NO bags, which isn't a great help, but it's something.

Generally, I use various search engines, then check the details on a few (or several) of the cheapest results.

The **extremely** flexible app from [Azuon.com](http://azuon.com/) includes the options in this image
[image]
Unfortunately, Azuon often as not tells me there are **no** flights from anywhere in North America to anywhere in (some other huge area) for an entire three-week period!

Comment: Interesting. Is that a windows app? A link might be useful

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/54301/what-is-the-most-advanced-flight-search-engine-besides-azuon-and-matrix

Comment: I found advice on other sites via Googling yesterday about this feature in Kayak. I found it problematic but got burned out with this stuff after too many hours and no longer recall the specific problems.

Comment: @MarkMayo, Azuon is a Windows app, but I used it on Mac with a Windows emulating wrapper called Wine.  I suspect it would also run in one of the Unix emulators or in a VM.  I spoke favorably of it in the question you linked to, but since that time it has developed serious deficiencies, as I mentioned in the last sentence of my answer.  I first reported such incidents to them at least eighteen months ago, and it is still happening.

Comment: @hippietrail, I haven't noticed "problems" with the Kayak feature other than the irritating fact that they constantly put it back to the default of zero every time I do anything.

Comment: @WGroleau: Maybe that was it. I might play with it later. The whole thing put me in a bad mood last night though. Not specifically Kayak but all the search engines and tips pages as a whole. So I forget the specific thing that made me stop persisting with Kayak after it was recommended.

Comment: Looks like a Windows 95 app.

Answer (score 7):

I book flights regularily and actually keep a list of hidden charges for the sites that come up near the top of any search regularily. Then, when I make a new search and see the prices listed, I simply add the hidden charges I know about in my head. Typically, the offers are close enough together that the hidden charges actually do make a difference.

It's a low-tech approach and it needs quite a few bookings (and going back out of a site because you consider their charges too high and picking another option) but by now I have a fairly complete list.

Comment: Yes I was about to find a notepad and do this myself! I ended up using a text file along with Mark Mayo's site though, so kind of a hybrid approach (-:

Answer (score 2):

Swede's have the option to use the website [Flygresor.se](https://www.flygresor.se/) which can include the surcharge for a checked bag and also for climate compensation and payment method.

The site only searches prices through Swedish travel agencies, not directly with the carriers. Because of this prices are only available in SEK and support is very limited. The airline selection could also be limited - hence I only recommend this site for Swedes but of course anyone could use it.

If I remember correctly Flygresor.se is a joint venture between all the major Swedish travel agencies.

[image: The Complete Price at Flygresor.se]

Comment: For Swedes only, but in English?  Is it not possible to find the two or three cheapest flights there, and then check elsewhere for a better price with similar parameters?

Comment: I usually do just that. I guess anyone could use it, but the airline selection could be limited. It's available in several languages - we have a lot of people here who aren't that good in Swedish - but the websites of the travel agencies could be Swedish-only and also require a Swedish adress.